# Multiple Conditions for Strings in Android Values -sw533dp and -zh

Tags: android, android-layout

My app is multi-language and it support tablet as well.

So now the conditon, For example: if device is tablet plus its chinese language.

How should i name the values folder?

values-zh-sw533dp? or values-sw533dp-zh?

Comment: Why do you only want to support Chinese strings on tablets? The size of the screen should have nothing to do with the language used.

Comment: that is just an example. I do have english as default, so I will also need values-sw533dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name would be `values-zh-sw533dp`. According to [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) qualifiers have to be specified in order they are listed in Table 2 of the same document.

However language strings should be present no matter the display size. Unless you need to display perhaps longer version of the same string as on phones.

Comment: What if I need to add another condition for landscape?

values-zh-sw533dp-land  or  values-zh-land-sw533dp?